# Prevent jQuery Flot to convert numbers to decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I found that the jquery flot adds extra decimal to numbers, so `12` will be come `12.00`.

Here is a sample:

```
$(function() {

  var data = [ [0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5],  [9, 13] ];

  $.plot($("#placeholder"), [data], {
    grid: {
      hoverable: true,
      clickable: true
    },
    series: { lines: {show: true},
              points:{show: true}
    }
  });

  $("<div id='tooltip'></div>").css({
    position: "absolute",
    display: "none",
    border: "1px solid #fdd",
    padding: "2px",
    "background-color": "#fee",
    opacity: 0.80
  }).appendTo("body");


  $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function(event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
      var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
        y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);

      $("#tooltip").html( "x is: " + x + " --  y is: " + y)
        .css({
          top: item.pageY + 5,
          left: item.pageX + 5
        })
        .fadeIn(200);
    } else {
      $("#tooltip").hide();
    }
  });

});
```

It shows a chart with tooltip. When you hover the mouse on the points you see

```
x is: 4.00 -- y is 8.00
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b22j666L/

How can I fix it ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `.toFixed(2)` in your code.

```
var x = item.datapoint[0];
var y = item.datapoint[1];
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b22j666L/1/)**</kbd>

Comment: How could I miss it !!

Answer (score 2):

These lines of codes make tooltip values to float.

```
var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(2),
    y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2);
```

To make x and y integer,

```
var x = item.datapoint[0],
    y = item.datapoint[1];
```